# How do I create a unit test case to get maximum code coverage for my debounce and throttle function using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, throttling, debouncing

I need to write unit tests for the library to get maximum code coverage - both line coverage and branch coverage.

```js
export const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
    let last = 0;
    return (...args) => {
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        if(now - last < delay) {
            return;
        }
        last = now;
        return fn(...args);
    }
}


export const debounce = ( fn, delay) => {
    let timeoutID;
    return function(...args){
        if (timeoutID){
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }
        timeoutID = setTimeout( () => {
            fn(...args);  
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

```js
import { throttle} from './throttle'
import { debounce} from './debounce'


document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener( "click", debounce(e => {
    console.log('clicked');
}, 2000))



document.getElementById('myid2').addEventListener('click', throttle(() => {
    console.log('you clicked me');
}, 5000));
```

I have the following denounce and throttle functions which get exported to the main js page. I am confused as to how to write test cases using jest for this. Every question that I have read using lodash but I just need a simple unit test case for these two functions. I am new to jest and after I read the documentation, I don't understand what the "expect to be" is here in denounce and throttle.
Can anyone please help me and provide some clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DOM related thing for unit testing. For testing `throttle`, you should mock the `Date`. For testing `debounce`, you should use fake timers. `Date` and `setTimeout` have side effects, we should mock them to get rid of side effects.

`throttle.js`:

```js
export const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let last = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - last < delay) {
      return;
    }
    last = now;
    return fn(...args);
  };
};
```

`throttle.test.js`:

```js
import { throttle } from './throttle';

describe('65593662', () => {
  describe('throttle', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    it('should call function if now - last > delay', () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();
      const throttledFn = throttle(fn, 1000);
      const getTimeSpy = jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getTime').mockReturnValue(2000);
      throttledFn('param');
      expect(fn).toBeCalledWith('param');
      expect(getTimeSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('should call function if now - last = delay', () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();
      const throttledFn = throttle(fn, 1000);
      const getTimeSpy = jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getTime').mockReturnValue(1000);
      throttledFn('param');
      expect(fn).toBeCalledWith('param');
      expect(getTimeSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('should not call function if now - last < delay', () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();
      const throttledFn = throttle(fn, 1000);
      const getTimeSpy = jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getTime').mockReturnValue(100);
      throttledFn('param');
      expect(fn).not.toBeCalled();
      expect(getTimeSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

`debounce.js`:

```js
export const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timeoutID;
  return function (...args) {
    if (timeoutID) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
};
```

`debounce.test.js`:

```js
import { debounce } from './debounce';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('65593662', () => {
  describe('debounce', () => {
    it('should call function if timeoutID is undefined', () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();

      const debouncedFn = debounce(fn, 1000);
      debouncedFn('param');
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
      expect(fn).toBeCalledWith('param');
      expect(fn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('should not call function once if timeoutID exists', () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();

      const debouncedFn = debounce(fn, 1000);
      debouncedFn('param');
      debouncedFn('param');
      debouncedFn('param');
      jest.runAllTimers();
      expect(fn).toBeCalledWith('param');
      expect(fn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65593662/throttle.test.ts
  65593662
    throttle
      ✓ should call function if now - last > delay (3 ms)
      ✓ should call function if now - last = delay
      ✓ should not call function if now - last < delay (1 ms)

 PASS  examples/65593662/debounce.test.ts
  65593662
    debounce
      ✓ should call function if timeoutID is undefined (5 ms)
      ✓ should not call function once if timeoutID exists (1 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 debounce.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 throttle.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.168 s
```

Comment: Hi, which command did you use to get the test result? was it npm test? When I pass it all the statements and branches are coming as 0. Also, I am getting an error saying cannot import out of the module.

Comment: Also, what is the function you are passing 655392?

Comment: @bros `65593662` is your question ID. I use it as the name of the test suite. I use `jest --coverage ./examples/65593662/throttle.test.ts` command to get the coverage report